# To convert copy command line from batch to powershell

Tags: powershell

How to convert the below copy line in batch line to powershell Copy-Item line:

`copy /Y %scr_src%\1.bat C:\1.bat` - where %scr_scr% indicates working directory inwhich "1.bat" file is located

Comment: @mklement0, ```%scr_scr%``` is the working directory inwhich 1.bat is located.

Comment: The working directory (aka current directory) and the directory in which a batch file is located are two unrelated things. It sounds like you're looking for the latter, however, so for that your batch file needs some reference point - what is that reference point in the original batch file? Is it the running batch file's own directory, accessible as `%~dp0`? To put it differently: please clarify how variable `src_src` is set in the original batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
$scr = 'C:\TEMP\test1'
$dst = 'C:\TEMP'
Copy-Item -Path "$scr\Test01.txt" -Destination $dst
```

This would copy the file to the destination folder with the same name. Or if you would like to change the name:

```
Copy-Item -Path "$scr\Test01.txt" -Destination "$dst\newname.txt"
```

If you know the name of the file and it is not a variable, you may include it in `$src` variable, like:

```
$scr = 'C:\TEMP\test1\Test01.txt'
$dst = 'C:\TEMP'
Copy-Item -Path $scr -Destination $dst
```

Comment: 1.bat file is to be copied from location where it is present and it might not be from C:\TEMP

Comment: you need to change the string in the variables, pointing to the right locations. This is something that I took from my environment, to demonstrate. I hope you may elaborate on that.

Comment: Eventually you may use copy-item with -force parameter if you would like to overwrite file if existing.